# Determine the Number of Integer Solutions $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 32$ with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**The Question**

[image]

**My Problem**

Part a is straight forward, just $C(35,32)$. I'm having a little difficulty with the restrictions and understanding what they mean. $x_1 > 0$ means we shouldn't have any solutions of the form $(0 + 32)$? If that's the case how would I factor that into my answer? I'm thinking taking the answer to part a and subtracting all the solutions which contain $32+0$ but I don't really know how to count those.

Comment: Hint: for $b)$ let $y_i=x_i+1$

Comment: @MarkBennet interesting, so I could kind of think of this as distributing 32 cookies amongst 4 children, where each child receives at least one cookie?

Comment: Indeed - if that helps you to get the idea. You can translate the others into the same language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part (b), $x_i > 0$ for all $i$, let $y_i = x_i - 1$.  Then the problem is equivalent to problem (a), only with a sum of 28 instead of 32 -- the answer is $C(31, 28) == C(31,3)$.

For part (c) let $y_i = x_i-5$ for $i\in \left\{ 1,2 \right\} $ and  $y_i = x_i-7 $ otherwise.  Then you have problem (a) again, with a sum of 8; the answer is $C(7,3)$.

For part (d) the same reasoning gives $C(3,3) = 1$.

For part (e) let  $y_i = x_i +2$ to get $C(39,3)$.

For part (f), you can start with the solution to (b), and subtract the cases where $x_4 > 25$.  To get the latter, do $y_4 = x_4 -25$, and find an answer of $C(10,3)$ so the answer to part (f) is $C(35,3) - C(10,3)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{S\ >\ 0}$:

\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{x_{1}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{2}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{3}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{4}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\delta_{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4},S}}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{x_{1}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{2}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{3}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{4}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{-x_{1} - x_{2} - x_{3} - x_{4} + S + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{S + 1}}
\pars{\sum_{x\ =\ 0}^{\infty}z^{x}}^{4}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{S + 1}\pars{1 - z}^{4}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{-4 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{S - k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\pars{-1}^{S}{-4 \choose S}
=\pars{-1}^{S}{4 + S - 1 \choose S}\pars{-1}^{S}
\\[5mm]&={S + 3 \choose 3}
=\color{#66f}{\large{\pars{S + 3}\pars{S + 2}\pars{S + 1} \over 6}}
\end{align}

  ${\bf a}$) $\ds{S = 32}$.
  $$
  {35 \times 34 \times 33 \over 6} = \color{#66f}{\large 6545}
  $$
  ${\bf b}$) $\ds{S = 28}$ because
  \begin{align}
  &\sum_{x_{1}\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
  \sum_{x_{2}\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{3}\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
  \sum_{x_{4}\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\delta_{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4},32}
  \\[5mm]&=\sum_{x_{1}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
  \sum_{x_{2}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{3}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
  \sum_{x_{4}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\delta_{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4},28}
  \end{align}

  $$
  {31 \times 30 \times 29 \over 6} = \color{#66f}{\large 4495}
  $$
  ${\bf c}$) $\ds{S = 8}$ because
  \begin{align}
  &\sum_{x_{1}\ =\ 5}^{\infty}
  \sum_{x_{2}\ =\ 5}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{3}\ =\ 7}^{\infty}
  \sum_{x_{4}\ =\ 7}^{\infty}\delta_{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4},32}
  \\[5mm]&=\sum_{x_{1}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
  \sum_{x_{2}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{3}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
  \sum_{x_{4}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\delta_{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4},8}
  \end{align}

  $$
  {11 \times 10 \times 9 \over 6} = \color{#66f}{\large 165}
  $$

> ${\tt\mbox{and so on}}$.

Answer (score 1):

For part f) we can use generating functions. The one that models f is

$$G(x)=\left(x+x^2+x^3+...+\right)^3 \left(x+x^2+...+x^{25}\right)$$

these are useful because they reduce combinatoric problems to computational ones. The above gf can be written:

$$g=\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^3 \cdot \frac{ \left(x-x^{26}\right)}{1-x}$$

Now we just need to get at the coefficient of $x^{32}$. I have done that already for you to keep the post small. The term of interest is $4475x^{32}$. So the answer is 4475.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have no idea what a generating function is (I think they save that for part II of my course). The answer is useful for someone who does though.

Comment: Hi; Did not mean to confuse you with too much. Just keep it in mind when you get to part II and good luck.